# Selenium Instance loses session data

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi. I am trying to run the following code and test case, such that

- The user is logged in
- The browser is closed
- The browser is started again.

Subsequently, code is executed to verify the  session still exists.

```
public void test()
{
  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://site/login");
  this.login();
  driver.quit();
  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://site/homepage");
  this.CheckSessionExist();  /// reutrn false as the session is lost

}
```

My question is: shouldn't I be able to retrieve the session after I initialize another driver instance? If this is not how it works, then how can I replicate this test case?

Comment: I believe starting a new instance of `ChromeDriver()` starts "clean", meaning that the login session you had previously is associated with a WebDriver instance that is now gone.

Comment: Is there way i can pass it on to the next instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion:

```
public void test()
{
  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // This opens a window
  driver.Navigate().GoToRul("https://www.google.com");  // Navigate to a dummy url, this is to keep the chrome driver session alive later
  IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body"));
  body.SendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + 't');  // This opens a new window

  String winHandleBefore = driver.CurrentWindowHandle();

  //Switch to new window opened
  foreach(String winHandle in driver.WindowHandles{
     if(winHandle !- winHandleBefore)
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(winHandle);
  }
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://site/login");
  this.login();
  driver.Close();  // This closes the current window, but should keep the ChromeDriver session alive
  driver.SwitchTo().Window(winHandleBefore);
  IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body"));
  body.SendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + 't');  // This opens a new window
  String winHandleBefore = driver.CurrentWindowHandle();

  //Switch to new window opened
  foreach(String winHandle in driver.WindowHandles{
     if(winHandle !- winHandleBefore)
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(winHandle);
  }
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://site/homepage");
  this.CheckSessionExist();  /// reutrn false as the session is lost
}
```

The idea here is you're

- Opening a dummy window to keep the current `ChromeDriver` session alive
- Opening a new window that you will use to navigate to your login test
- Switch to that new window, navigate to the url
- Login
- Close that window
- Switch back to the original window with the dummy url
- Open another new window
- Navigate to the home page
- Ensure your session is still alive

Probably overly complicated, and a better solution likely exists.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the cookies before closing the browser, open new browser, navigate to same domain and drop cookies